# Вывод текста при нажатии на div

Tags: javascript, html, css, css3, html5

Мне необходимо, чтобы при нажатии на div с классом tab-link, ниже выводился ещё один div с классом
tab-link-list. Заранее спасибо!

```
<div class="tab-link">
    Общие Правила
    <div class="tab-link-list">
        <li class="tab-link-list-li">Правила Администрации</li>
        <li class="tab-link-list-li">Правила «AWP #2»</li>
        <li class="tab-link-list-li">Правила «AWP #2»</li>
        <li class="tab-link-list-li">Правила «AWP #2»</li>
        <li class="tab-link-list-li">Правила «AWP #2»</li>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Он и без каких-либо нажатий выводится, ибо есть в разметке (только не как "еще один", а как дочерний элемент). Задача не ясна, суть вопроса тоже - их желательно уточнить редактированием.

Comment: Для начала `<div class="tab-link-list">` надо заменить на `<ul class="tab-link-list">`, ибо <li> - это вложенный элемент для <ol> или <ul> но никак не для <div>

Comment: `let tablink = document.querySelector('.tab-link');

tablink.onclick = function(event) {//запускаем функцию как только нажали на элемент с классом tab-link
  let target = event.target;
  //выведем target и this и посмотрим чем они отличаются
  console.log(this);
  console.log(target);
}`

Comment: Там где происходит вывод target и this и нужно написать логику для вывода нужного блока. Почитайте про .innerHTML должно помочь. А вообще для js лучше использовать не классы а атрибуты. Например, элементу с классом tab-link можно добавить атрибут data-obj(название произвольное): data-obj="tab-link" и обращаться к элементу через селектор атрибута.

Answer (score 1):

```js
const tabLink = document.querySelector('.tab-link');

tabLink.addEventListener('click', (ev) => {
  ev.target.querySelector('.tab-link-list').classList.toggle('active');
});
```

```css
.tab-link-list {
  display: none;
}

.tab-link-list.active {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<div class="tab-link">
  Общие Правила
  <ul class="tab-link-list">
    <li class="tab-link-list-li">Правила Администрации</li>
    <li class="tab-link-list-li">Правила «AWP #2»</li>
    <li class="tab-link-list-li">Правила «AWP #2»</li>
    <li class="tab-link-list-li">Правила «AWP #2»</li>
    <li class="tab-link-list-li">Правила «AWP #2»</li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Надо использовать jqwery, так проще.

```js
function show_list(){
    if ($('#list').is(':visible')){
        $('#list').hide();
    }
    else{
        $('#list').show();
    }
}
```

```css
.tab-link-list{
    display:none;
}
```

```html
<div class="tab-link" onclick="show_list()">
    Общие Правила
    <div id="list" class="tab-link-list">
        <li class="tab-link-list-li">Правила Администрации</li>
        <li class="tab-link-list-li">Правила «AWP #2»</li>
        <li class="tab-link-list-li">Правила «AWP #2»</li>
        <li class="tab-link-list-li">Правила «AWP #2»</li>
        <li class="tab-link-list-li">Правила «AWP #2»</li>
    </div>
</div>
```